# Audio visualization with HTML5 and JavaScript only outputs zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am trying to create an Audio visualizer in JavaScript to display on a website. I want the visualizer to work locally (so no nodejs or servers). This is what I have so far:

```
var audioContext,mediaElementSource,analyzer,analyzerBytes;

function initAudio(){
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.source = 'music.mp3';
    audio.loop = true;


    if (!audioContext){

        audioContext = new AudioContext();
        mediaElementSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        analyzer = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        mediaElementSource.connect(analyzer);
        analyzer.connect(audioContext.destination);
        analyzerBytes = new Uint8Array(analyzer.frequencyBinCount);
        audio.play();

        window.setInterval(function() {

          analyzer.getByteFrequencyData(analyzerBytes);
          console.log(analyzerBytes);


        }, 50);
    }
}
```

I also have an Audio element in my index.html file which looks like this:

```
<audio controls="controls" src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"onplay="initAudio()"></audio>
```

My problem is that when I play the audio (which works fine) the console shows that the analyzerBytes array only contains zeros. This means that I am not getting the frequencies what what is playing and can therefore not make any visualization of the information.

Have I missed something or am I doing it completely wrong? I have been searching around and seen other peoples solutions to the problem but when I try their code I still only get an array full of zeros where as they get it full of frequencies.

Comment: There are many issues here, with the functionality as well as construction. The main issue is that you're assigning a path to a non-native property: `source` should be `src`. Then you use two audio elements when there's only need for one. ++

Comment: @K3N This is my first attempt at something like this. Where exactly am I using two audio elements?

Comment: The first one is defined in the html, then inside the function `audio = new Audio();` (as the code is shown `audio` will end up on the `window` object). The latter is the one being used for the audio-analyer, but there is no audio playing from this one, only the html one, since the src is not correctly set (and there needs to be an oncanplay or similar event to make sure you have actual data). Even more, every time is played in the html element the function is run again and will reset the `audio`.